# Что такое реактивная зависимость?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, реактивное-программирование

В документации vue.js встретился [такой фрагмент](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

> Обратите внимание, что следующее вычисляемое свойство никогда не
>   обновится, поскольку Date.now() не является реактивной зависимостью:
>
> ```
> computed: {
>   now: function () {
>     return Date.now()
>   }
> }
> ```

Несколько вопросов на понимание:

- Что считается "реактивной" зависимостью?
- Как понять какая зависимость является реактивной, а какая - нет?
- Почему `Date.now()` не является реактивной зависимостью?

Comment: Суть в том, что никто не слушает изменения `Date.now()`, следовательно и __реакции__ никакой не будет

Comment: Реактивность - грубо говоря зависимость. Допустим при изменении одной переменной у вас будет пересчитываться другая и обновляться на элементе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Своими словами:

> Что считается "реактивной" зависимостью?

Св-во или переменная которая может сообщить об своем изменении. В данном случае, сам `Vue`, если посмотреть под капот, то передавая `Vue` объект, он превращает каждое его св-во в `setter/getter` и теперь он способен **реагировать** на изменения этих св-во.

> Как понять какая зависимость является реактивной, а какая - нет?

Если св-во или переменная может сообщить об своем изменении

> Почему Date.now() не является реактивной зависимостью

Потому что при изменении `Date.now` не происходит ничего. Мы по идее даже не можем как-то нативно подписаться на его изменения. Придется городить свои велосипеды

#### Не своими словами:

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: А, я значит не дочитал ещё до этого раздела. В принципе, я не до конца понял, как глядя на тот или иной участок кода понять реактивен он или нет (только глядя на data у Vue, верно?) - но направление в целом понятно.